# AngularDart Material Color Theming

Tags: angular-dart, angular-components

How can I change the material color scheme for a web app using AngularDart 5 and angular_components?

I don't want to define a color for every attribute of every component, but rather use the schemes provided by the color tool or material.io.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/253#issuecomment-384441704

> Today to do this we use mixins to style the specific parts of the app in the different theme with it scoped to the components in question.

See also

- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components#custom-component-styles
- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/app_layout/README.md
- https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/176

Comment: I've ready through those links, yet I sitll dont fully understand how to use a different theme. in that first link you provide, they mention to use mixins and the code provided in the example comments is no longer valid and consider that system deprecated. But I cant seem to find a mixin theme example to change to a red/blue/yellow theme for example

Comment: @james I haven't worked with Angular since quute some time. I'll try to figure out and update my answer. Might take a bit.